# Explanation for an unordered sampling with replacement question

Tags: combinatorics

**Q**. You go to a bakery to select some baked goods for a dinner
party. You need to choose a total of 12 items. The baker has seven different types
of items from which to choose, with lots of each type available. How many different
boxfuls of 12 items are possible for you to choose?

**A**. ${7+12−1\choose 12} = 18,564 \ \text{boxes}$

---

I've been trying for an hour, but I absolutely don't understand how to answer this question. I couldn't even figure it out looking at the given answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks $\sum_{i=1}^{7} x_i = 12$ where $x_i$ are number of different types of items. We have $x_i \ge 0$, so use stars and bars to get $\binom{7+12-1}{12}$.

Comment: thank you! i wasn't aware of the stars and bars method. quite a creative approach.

Comment: @zac hmm its very popular!